# Expected of number of discrete uniform variables whose sum is bigger than k (from characteristic function of discrete Irwin–Hall distribution?)

Tags: expected-value, characteristic-functions

### The problem

Imagine we keep uniformly drawing $n$ integers $X_i$ from {0, 1, ..., 9} so that their sum is more than $10$. For instance, one draw would be {1, 0, 2, 5, 3}, hence $n=5$, and repeat this procedure over and over. What would the expected value of $n$ be (analytically calculated)?
By simulation (over 10 million trials), it is 3.063577.

Apparently, if that were uniformly drawn from $[0,10]$, this expected value would be equal to the Euler number $e$.

[I very recently asked it [on Mathematics StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3517395/expected-of-number-of-discrete-uniform-variables-whose-sum-is-bigger-than-k-fro) and am waiting for answers (and will post them here), but I thought maybe it may be more suitable for CV. Sorry if that makes it off-topic.]

### What I have been trying to do

Consulting the paper [*Polynomial coefficients and distribution of the sum of discrete uniform variables*](http://community.dur.ac.uk/c.c.d.s.caiado/multinomial.pdf) by Caiado & Rathie (2007), I suspect (given $Y = \sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i$) the characteristic function of the distribution of $Y$ is something of the following form (Equation 2.3 in the paper)

$$ \Phi_Y(t) = \left( \sum_{p=0}^{k} \frac{e^{i.t.p}}{k+1} \right)^n , \forall t \in \mathbb{R}, i=\sqrt{-1} $$

If I understand it correctly, $k$ should be equal to 9 (right?)

If I have been correct, I tried calculating the inverse Fourier transform of $\Phi_Y(t)$ for $k=9$ and calculate its expected value but it is getting too complicated—and I suspect I'm very wrong here.

I went through multiple "similar" questions on SE (e.g., [+](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3511059/probability-of-sum-of-k-discrete-uniform-random-variables-smaller-than-n),
[+](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1169074/sum-of-discrete-and-continuous-random-variables-with-uniform-distribution),
[+](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2047713/distribution-of-sum-of-discrete-and-uniform-random-variables),
[+](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/315280/characteristic-function-and-expected-value),
[+](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1255815/expected-value-of-characteristic-function),
and [+](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1426207/deducing-expectation-from-characteristic-function-without-using-l%C3%A9vys-formula))
but I'm too confused to infere something useful from them.

Is there an answer to my question?

Many thanks in advance!

---

### Some `R` code for numerical estimation

This is the `R` code I used to calculate it numerically (edited since the first submission):

```
N <- 1e+7
s.list <- n.list <- rep(NA, N)

for(i in 1:N){
  s <- 0
  n <- 0
  seed <- i
  while(s < 11){
    s <- s + (sample(10, 1, replace = TRUE) - 1)
    n <- n + 1
  }
  if(!(i %% 10000)) print(paste("At iteration", round(i/1000,1), "K, s is", s, "and n is", n))
  s.list[i] <- s
  n.list[i] <- n
}

answer <- mean(n.list)
```

Comment: The right way to think about this is in terms of solving the Renewal Equation for a positive integer valued random variable. You can directly solve this in the case of $\{1,2,...,9\}$ using a markov chain to calculate $E[S_T]$, using the same technique I used here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3456268/the-case-of-the-missing-ninth-of-a-2%e2%82%ac-coin/3500175#3500175 . Your problem involves the possibility of 0 but in this case it is a minor complication -- you still have $E[S_T] = E[T]\cdot \bar{X}$ by the Wald Equation and $E[S_T]$ doesn't change by allowing 0 as a possibility.

Comment: You wrote "Imagine we keep uniformly drawing  integers 
from $\{0,1,...,9\}$ so that their sum is more than 10." This implies a stopping rule of stop when sum is at least 11, which contradicts what your code says. Also a stopping rule threshold of 11 implies an expected value >3.  Supposing you have 10 as a stopping rule, I computed the result using the method in my above comment (exactly, via sympy), as well as directly via an absorbing state markov chain.  In both cases the  result is $\frac{10000000000}{3486784401}$

Comment: Thanks @user8675309. You're right, I've made that mistake in my code; the sum should be more than 10, so stopping threshold of 11. Also, why does that imply an expected value of > 3?

Comment: Also dear @user8675309, after posting it here, I also asked the question on [CV](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/445818/expected-of-number-of-discrete-uniform-variables-whose-sum-is-bigger-than-k-fro) (as that SE could be also a fit for the question.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem, as @whuber has elaborated on in [his answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/445836/142674) on the same question I asked on CrossValidated, can be solved through the probability generating function of $X_i$ and calculating the expected value of the sum by means of its survival function.

The answer is thus
$$\frac{10}{9}\left(\left(\frac{9}{10}\right)^{-10} - \frac{1}{9}\right) = \frac{96125795110}{31381059609} \approx 3.063178755201$$